# Need Help with JQuery UTC Date function

Tags: jquery, datetime, utc

I am trying to use the Jquery Countdown plugin but I am having trouble with my UTC Date formatting.

The date I wish to countdown to is Friday 23rd July 2010.

Here is the relevant code...

```
until: $.countdown.UTCDate(2010,  7 - 1, 23), 
                format: 'YOD',
```

The output is just 00.00.00 etc

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#UTCDate

The first parameter to UTCDate should be your timezone offset:

```
$.countdown.UTCDate(+10, 2010,  7 - 1, 23)
```